# Plone 4 Admin menu

Tags: menu, admin, plone

The Admin dropdown on a new plone 4 instance isn't providing the dropdown it just takes me to the admin dashboard...does anyone have any suggestions or insight?

I have two sites that live on the same server:  one admin menu works, one does not.  everything else on the site with the broken menu seems to work fine.

I've been testing both sites in different tabs in the same IE browser instance.  Help would be appreciated!

Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing some issue with your javascript support. Is it enabled in your browser, right? Using firebug, do you see some error in the js console?

Anyway there was a ticket for providing a not-js fallback ([#10794](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/10794)). It was closed but we will reopen it and fix it.

**Edit**:
The ticket has been solved. Next releases will carry the fix.